# Coq to OCaml extraction of algebraic types

Tags: types, ocaml, coq

When I extract the following Coq data types to OCaml:

```
Inductive Foo := | A | B.
Inductive Bar (f:Foo) := | C | D.
Extraction Language Ocaml.
Extraction "test.ml" Foo Bar.
```

I get the following ML code:

```
type foo =
| A
| B

type bar =
| C
| D
```

The 'bar' type is different from Coq's as it does have 'f' as a part of its type signature.

What is the best way to define such types so they are extracted well to OCaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't: OCaml does not support indexing types by term values and as a consequence things such as `Bar A` do not make sense in it. Coq is forced to erase the extra indices so that the definitions are compatible with OCaml's type system.

Comment: I understand this. What would be the types which would work both in Coq in OCaml to represent something like this?